Momentum Eigenstates for Particle in a Box
The following lines as attached as photos taken from Beiser Modern Physics (6th Edition):

Now these equations and wavefunctions make no sense to me at all, first of all how are these wavefunctions for a particle in a box, they clearly do not satisfy the boundary conditions.
Am I missing something or this just straight up incorrect.

Maybe they are working with periodic boundary conditions?

@JosBergervoet No, as far as I am aware it's the standard Particle in a box scenario.

In that case it is indeed strange to call them "eigenfunctions for a particle in a box". They may be eigenfunctions but they are not solutions for a particle in a box. Still they could be used to create correct solutions if they are combined with some restrictions (coefficients must sum to zero). So apart from the use of language, we do not yet see a real error here...

I mean isn't the first line in your image exactly the context of the analysis? They tell you that the actual solutions...the energy eigenfunctions are a linear combination of the negative and positive momentum eigenfunctions.

Don't use images/screenshot for text and equations. Instead, use Mathjax, i.e. type the relevant passage.

@Triatticus, but shouldn't these eigenfunctions also satisfy the boundary conditions ?

@L lawliet That's how I also see it. Momentum eigenfunctions, if they exist, should also fulfill the box boundary conditions.

@Jos Bergervoet The exponentials are momentum eigenfunctions for a system with periodicity L condition, not for the box boundary 0 condition.

I'm not sure what you mean: is there another linear momentum operator for the particle in a box? To me there is one linear momentum operator $\hat{p}: L^2(\mathbb{R}) \to L^2(\mathbb{R})$ (for this particular situation). @freecharly

I'm not sure what edition you are using, but those are not the correct equations numbers for the sixth edition of Beiser's book.  And in all the editions I can find, including the sixth, in the actual equations that appear, he uses the correct $\sin$ wave functions for the particle in the hard-walled box.

Any infinite box energy eigenfunction can be expressed only by a specific linear combination of the complex exponentials, namely the difference of (5.49) and (5.50), which gives (except for a constant factor) a real sinus(πnx/L) satisfying the boundary condition 0 at x=0 and x=L. The exponentials don't. By differentiation one can easily see that these energy eigenfunction are not eigenfunctions of the momentum operator. Also, the  momentum expectation value of these energy eigenfunctions is always zero. It is not clear why the book claims that the complex exponentials are the momentum eigenfunctions.

This confusion seems to be with (1) strange wording by the text and (2) solving boundary value problems, not with the particulars of this problem.
A boundary value problem is finding the solution to a particular differential equations subject to conditions imposed at the boundary of the solution. The "particle in a box" Schrödinger equation is the free particle Schrödinger equation (a differential equation) with a boundary condition, namely that the wave function vanishes at the edges of the box.
In a boundary value problem, we generally solve for a complete set of "basis vectors" that span the entire solution space of the differential equation. In this case, the "basis vectors" are the periodic free particle wave functions that you have written. Then, a solution to the differential equation subject to boundary conditions can be found by taking an arbitrary linear combination of "basis vectors" and then imposing the boundary conditions.
Then, to directly answer your question: the momentum eigenstates are the "basis vectors" for the solution space of the "particle in a box" Schrödinger equation. To get an actual solution to your problem, you need to consider an arbitrary linear combination of such "basis vectors" and then impose your boundary condition(s).

If you have done some electromagnetism, this is the exact same procedure as used to solve Laplace's equation in electrostatics.

I am not sure about the way you are looking at it. By the same approach you would get for the Schrödinger equation (Hamilton operator H) first plane the wave solutions of the unbounded problem which has a continuous energy eigenwert spectrum. This is not a basis of the Hilbert space of  the quantum well. The Hilbert space of the well is spun by the discrete set of sine eigenfunctions which satisfy the  boundary conditions. These eigenfunctions of H are a complete set of basis vectors of the Hilbert space of the well. The momentum operator doesn't seem to have such eigenvectors.
